# Lenovo Yoga 2 - 13" | Will not switch on

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

Hi guys so i have a Lenovo Yoga 2 13" which simply will not respond. This happened out of the blue. Battery died, won't switch on again.

I get a white light on battery light with power supply plugged in.

When i press the Power Button i get a white light on it for around 5 seconds and then nothing.

I have tried removing the battery and holding Power Button for 30 seconds, 90 seconds etc .. but nothing.

This particular model does not appear to have a CMOS battery it only has a soldered in RTC.

I am stumped really .. Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with the battery out, power cord in (duh)?

Comment: Thanks for your response .. Yes i've tried on solo battery power, solo mains power, combination of both with battery in and out .. the symptoms are identical.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, RAM is soldered on this model. It's possible that your RAM module died on you, and there's not much else to do but take it to a shop nearby (not easy these days, what with lockdown and all), or contact Lenovo Support (https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/contactus) with the details of your PC. They'll get back to you or will even chat with you to discuss your options. Meanwhile, other users here may have some input on your situation, but I honestly think your PC is toast.

Comment: Yes unfortunately everything in this machine is onboard ... Literally only HDD can be removed ... I fear it may be toast also ! Appreciate your response !

Comment: Anytime. I hope I'm wrong, though.